# fft() как посчитать амплитуду, фазу , частоту временного ряда

Tags: r, fft

Есть у нас какой то временной ряд

```
x <- cumsum(rnorm(100))
```

Как с помощью преобразования Фурье `fft()`
можно посчитать амплитуды, фазы, и частоты временного ряда `х`

Comment: А ... Вы уже прочитали, как интерпретировать результаты  Фурье?

Comment: Нет, честно говоря я слабо в этом разбираюсь. Мне нужно кластеризировать ряд по каким то характеристикам, я думаю что частоты и амплитуды гармоник ряда для этого хорошо подойдут

Answer (score 1):

Выполнить преобразование Фурье средствами R особой проблемы нет. Ну, например:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spectral/spectral.pdf

http://www.di.fc.ul.pt/~jpn/r/fourier/fourier.html

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/fft.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010605/fast-fourier-transform-in-r

и т.д. Вот только поможет-ли это вам в задаче кластеризации временных рядов - отдельный вопрос. Вообще-то "кластеризация временных рядов" - сама по себе отдельная и весьма нетривиальная (как кажется на первый взгляд) тема.